# Is it possible to use SQLMAP against an ODBC driver connection?

Tags: python, security, connection, odbc, sqlmap

Is it possible to use sqlmap against an ODBC connection so that I can test the database with SQLMAP if there are some vulnerabilities? Maybe is it possible to use SQLMAP in the context of pyodbc?

I want to test if the ODBC driver has some vulnerabilities and therefore wanted to run sqlmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.. SQL Map is primarily a tool to do all kind of injection attacks across the well known databases . The injection vulnerabilities are a result of lack of or improper input sanitization at the application level .

The ODBC driver however is more like a protocol handler for a particular database , where on one end it connects over the database over the network and on the other side interacts with the database library used by the programmer in the application .

Typically just like other software , ODBC drivers may have vulnerabilities due to the usage of other vulnerable components / libraries used for the development. Though other things also may exists due to poor coding , lack of validation and improper bounds check.